# Mercurial: is it possible to compress .hg folder to several large BLOBs?

Tags: performance, mercurial, clone

Issue: cloning mercurial repository over network takes too much time (`~ 12 minutes`). We suspect it is because `.hg` directory contains a lot of files (`> 15 000`).

We also have `git` repository which is even larger, but clone performance is quite good - around `1 minute`. Looks like it's because `.git` folder which is transferred over network has only several files (usually `< 30`).

**Question:** does Mercurial support "repository compressing to single blob" and if it does how to enable it?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Mercurial version: 1.8.3

Access method: SAMBA share (`\\server\path\to\repo`)

Mercurial is installed on Linux box, accessed from Windows machines (by Windows domain login)

Comment: What version of Mercurial are you using ? The network protocol has been improved a lot lately. Also, what method do you use (ssh, http, etc) and what is serving your repo ?

Comment: Question updated. But I believe transferring 15 000 files would be slow over any protocol, unless this protocol internally sends them as a single blob.

Answer (score 5):

Mercurial use some kind of compression to send data on the network ( see http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/behind-the-scenes.html#id358828 ), but by using Samba, you totally bypass this mechanism. Mercurial thinks the remote repository is on a local filesystem and the mechanism used is different.

It clearly says in the linked documentation that each data are compressed as a whole before sending :

> This combination of algorithm and compression of the entire stream
>   (instead of a revision at a time) substantially reduces the number of
>   bytes to be transferred, yielding better network performance over most
>   kinds of network.

So you won't have the problem of 15'000 files you use a "real" network protocol.

BTW, I strongly recommend against using something like Samba to share your repository. This is really asking for various kind of problems :

- lock problems when multiple people attempt to access the repository at the same time
- file right problems
- file stats problems
- problems with symlink management if used

You can find information about publishing repositories on the wiki : [PublishingRepositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories) (where you can see that samba is not recommended at all)

And to answer the question, AFAIK, there's no way to compress the Mercurial metadata or anything like that like reduce the number of files. But if the repository is published correctly, this won't be a problem anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You could compress it to a blob by creating a bundle:

- `hg bundle --all \\server\therepo.bundle`
- `hg clone \\server\therepo.bundle`
- `hg log -R therepo.bundle`

You do need to re-create or update the bundle periodically, but creating the bundle is fast and could be done in a post-changeset hook on the server, or nightly. (Since fetching remaining changesets can be done by pulling the repo after cloneing from bundle, if you set [paths] correctly in .hg/hgrc).

So, to answer your question about several blobs, you could create a bundle every X changesets, and have the clients clone/unbundle each of those. (However, having a single one updated regularly + a normal pull for any remaining changesets seems easier...)

However, since you're running Linux on the server anyway, I suggest running hg-ssh or hg-web.cgi. That's what we do and it works well for us. (With windows clients)